# vue2 data change not updating view

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I have a simple file upload component FileUpload.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()" ref="file">
    <button class="btn shadow-lg first" @click="addFiles()">SELECT FILE</button>
    <button class="btn shadow-lg" v-on:click="handleSubmit()">UPLOAD</button>
    <p> {{uploadPercentage}} </p>

</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
name: 'FileUpload',
data() {
    return {
        file: '',
        uploadPercentage: 0

    }
},

methods: {
    handleFileUpload: () => {
        this.file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    },
    addFiles: () => {
        document.getElementById('file').click();
    },
    handleSubmit: () => {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.file);
        axios.post('/file/create',
        formData,
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                console.log(this.uploadPercentage);
                this.uploadPercentage = parseInt(Math.round(progressEvent.loaded * 100 / progressEvent.total));
            }
        }
        )
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
}
}
</script>
```

The data **uploadPercentage** is initialized to 0. As the file upload starts, the **uploadPercentage** value changes in the **onUploadProgress** method. 
If I console log **uploadPercentage**, it shows the changes in the value. It goes from 0 to 100.

```
console.log(this.uploadPercentage)
```

But in my view, **uploadPercentage** never changes. It always shows the initial value 0.

```
<p> {{uploadPercentage}} </p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that you should not use arrow functions as methods in the Vue instance definition, because otherwise `this` in the method will not point to the Vue instance itself and you will not be able to access `data` properties. You may check the definition in the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Description)

Comment: That solves the problem. Thanks, @Slim. Changed the arrow functions and it became reactive.